# Send email using an event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

New to asp.net.

Trying to set up an event handler that will send me an email when a button is clicked on my asp.net website.  My hosting provider tells me to use "localhost" as the smtp server name.  Here's the code:

```
protected void returnToMenuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage("sender@abc.net", "receiver@xyz.com", "Results", "This is a test.");
        NetworkCredential objNC = new NetworkCredential("sender@abc.net", "SENDERPASSWORD");
        SmtpClient objsmtp = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
        objsmtp.Credentials = objNC;
        objsmtp.Send(objMail);            
    }
```

I haven't changed anything in my web.config file.  When I click on the button, nothing happens.  I just get redirected to another webpage as I had designed it.

Comment: Are you running a SMTP server on your website host? Some SMTP servers will block invalid email-addresses or addresses not hosted on that server.

Comment: The hosting company gave the following parameters: smtp server name: local host; port: 25.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to check for errors and contact your hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

please put 'try' 'catch' and check whether you are getting any error. Also check whether port 25 is open.